# Transform a list of strings to JSON array using jq

Tags: json, string, jq, convertto-json

Having a list of strings (one per line) like

```
str1
str2
...
```

how do I convert these into the JSON list `["str1", "str2", ...]`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming that the input is given on stdin, the following command solves the problem:

```
jq -Rn '[inputs]'
```

The flag `-R` reads the input as "raw" (i.e. unquoted strings) and `-n` hands over stdin to `inputs` (slurping with `-s` doesn't work because when combined with `-R`, it reads the whole input a single string). Add `-c` to print the JSON on one line like in the question.

Any empty lines (like a trailing newline) may be skipped by adding a little filter:

```
jq -Rn '[inputs|select(length>0)]'
```

---

If the strings are separated by other characters like `,`, the string may be split with

```
jq -R 'split(",")'
```

This could be used to split on `\n` as well for solving the above case, but my (unverified) assumption is that the above solution is more portable with systems using other line terminators.